How to approach this complex integration problem
Let $\gamma(t)= e^{it}, 0\leq t \leq 6\pi$. Then the value of the integral $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int _ {\gamma}\frac{z^{99}}{z^{100}-1}dz$$ equals?
We can't use Cauchy integral formula or residue theorem here, right?
I tried using argument principle also, but if we choose $f(z)={z^{100}-1}$, the zeroes will lie in the path and hence we can't use argument principle either.
Then how to solve this problem? kindly help

The integrand is not continuous at the curve (because, as you said, the zeroes of the denominator lie on the curve), so the integral cannot be computed.

given any contour radius other than one, you can compute it

@CSquared Yes,.

The integral can be interpreted as a Cauchy Principal Value integral.

Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

@MarkViola Sorry to Response late Mark, I was solving some random questions from internet, and I got this question, as This was given as a  MCQ with 4 integer options I thought it can be solved by something like CIF or CIFD or Residue theorem, or Argument principle, but as I noticed there is poles on the path, so we can use none of them as Julio and Csquared confirmed it... and I just now saw your answer of using Cauchy Principle value ( I shall read what's that says) and I think this is good enough currently, Thank you so much

You're welcome.  My pleasure.

The integral does not exist since there are poles on $\gamma$.  However, we may interpret the integral as a Cauchy principal value as follows.
Let $0<\varepsilon<1$ and let $\gamma^{\pm}(t)=(1\pm \varepsilon)e^{it}$ for $t\in [0,6\pi]$. We define the Cauchy Principal Value as
$$\text{PV}\oint_\gamma \frac{z^{99}}{z^{100}-1}\,dz=\frac12\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(\oint_{\gamma^-} \frac{z^{99}}{z^{100}-1}\,dz+\oint_{\gamma^+} \frac{z^{99}}{z^{100}-1}\,dz\right)$$
Inasmuch as $\frac{z^{99}}{z^{100}-1}$ is holomorphic in and on $\gamma^-$, Cauchy's integral theorem guarantees that
$$\oint_{\gamma^-}\frac{z^{99}}{z^{100}-1}\,dz=0$$
For the integration over $\gamma^+$, we note that
$$\frac{z^{99}}{z^{100}-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{c_n}{z-e^{i2n\pi/100}}$$
where $c_n=1/100$, which can be found by applying L'Hospital's Rule.  Note that the integral over $\gamma^+$ is independent of $\varepsilon$.
Hence, using the Residue Theorem reveals
$$\oint_{\gamma^+}\frac{z^{99}}{z^{100}-1}\,dz=100\,\left(3\, (2\pi i) \left( \frac1{100}\right)\right)$$
Putting it all together, we find that
$$\frac1{2\pi i}\text{PV}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{z^{99}}{z^{100}-1}\,dz=\frac32$$
